# Damaged glass shield of diode

Tags: diodes, damage

I was repairing a PCB, when I noticed that a diode is damaged.

The glass shield is missing a piece but the gap is still covered.
Is the diode still ok?

I don't know how to replace it since part of the writing is missing :/

PS: Here is a video of the diode: https://youtu.be/vms3SuanZtE

PPS:
Voltcraft VC920:
Forward resistance: ~3 M ohm
Reverse resistance: overload
Forward Voltage: 0,63V
Reverse Voltage: overload

PPPS: Seems to be a Schottky or Switching diode, not a Zener.

Comment: To replace a zener, you would at minimum need to determine the zener voltage and put a bound on the current it is subjected to.  In some circuits other aspects such as capacitance may matter (it is not unheard of to use a zener diode like a varactor as variable capacitance in a voltage controlled oscillator).

Comment: @Tie-fighter - in addition to the helpful replies so far from ChrisStratton & transistor, you said: "part of the writing is missing". From your newly added video, it looks like *some* characters are still readable. *Any* characters from the existing markings may help you to narrow-down the choices for a replacement part. I recommend that you note those characters before any more are lost!

Answer (score 5):

Even with a photo (hint) it would be difficult to say.

If it was removed from circuit you could hook it up to a bench power supply and figure out it's reverse breakdown voltage. Since the device is weak I wouldn't attempt to remove it unless the whole circuit had ceased operation and an attempt at repair is required.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9jf6S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Test circuit.*

Test the Zener with your multimeter diode test circuit. You should get 0.7 to 1 V in the forward direction and open circuit in reverse. If that's good then ..

Hook up the suspect zener as shown. You'll have to guess what voltage to test with. 12 V would be a good starting point. The voltage on the multimeter should be the reverse breakdown voltage. If you read the same voltage at both ends of the resistor then the Zener hasn't conducted yet so you'll have to raise the voltage.

Comment: I already removed it to inspect it :/

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Voltcraft VC920:
Forward resistance: overload
Reverse resistance: ~3 M ohm
Forward Voltage: 0,63V
Reverse Voltage: overload

Comment: +1 good advice. From the size, I would say a 500mW zener diode  should work okay.

Comment: @Tie-fighter: Did you try the test circuit yet to measure the breakdown voltage?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't break down up to 70V.
It seems I was wrong from the beginning and it is a schottky or switching diode. I was misleaded by the glass packaging.

Comment: 1N4148 and 1N914, regular small signal diodes were glass packaged. I'd say it's one of those.